# Tabbed application (template), need one controller to have a static table view

Tags: ios, xcode

I just created a new xcode project with the 'Tabbed Application' template.  I have a tabbed application with two tabs therefore two controllers.  Both controllers are of type UIViewController.  I made one of my controllers the 'settings' controller.  I added a nav bar with a title of 'Settings'.  All is well so far.

Then I add a TableView to the settings controller and make it a static table.  Apparently I cannot have a static table view inside of a normal ViewController, it needs to live in a TableViewController.

Here is where I get very lost (still very new to iOS programming).

1. Am I supposed to delete the ViewController that the template provided and add a new TableViewController?  I tried this however I cannot add a navbar to this type of controller.
2. Or is there some way to shove a TableViewController into the ViewController to get things to work.

I have looked all over today and most examples of TableViewControllers I have found are not in a tabbed application so they just create a TableViewController and move on.

Oh I also need to be compatible with iOS 5.  Not sure if that makes a difference with TableViewController stuff.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update**: other option: you can follow [this tutorial](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can:

1. Delete de UIViewController
2. Add to your storyborad a new TableViewController
3. Select it and go to Editor Menu->Embed In->Navigation Controller
4. Connect it to your tabbar in the storyboard

Update: other option: you can follow this tutorial too: [Tutorial: Storyboard in XCode 4.2 with Navigation Controller and Tabbar Controller (Part 1)](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: So I changed this, added new UITableViewController classes, and left the generated code alone.  Now my static tables show up empty, i.e. stuff from my storyboard does not show up.

Comment: Some checks: 1-Your UITableViewController is assigned to the view in the StoryBoard. 2-Since you are using static cells (I asumme that they are configured in the StoryBoard), delete de methods: `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.